# Test jquery selector in jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a function `muteVideos` as follows:

```
  private muteVideos() {
    $('video').prop('muted', true);
  }
```

I am able to test that the `prop` function is called with arguments `'muted', true` as follows

```
jest.spyOn($.fn,'prop')
expect($.fn.prop).toBeCalledWith('muted',true);
```

But I also want to test that the `$` function is being called with the `video` selector. [Somewhere](https://www.codeguru.co.in/2021/04/how-to-mock-jquery-selector-using-jest.html#:%7E:text=note%3A%20when%20we%20call%20%24(%E2%80%9D%23someid%E2%80%9D)%20jquery%20call%20the%20%E2%80%9Cinit%E2%80%9D%20method.) I read that internally `$` function calls `init` function so I tried spying on `init` but I can't find API reference for this function so I don't know which parameter is for the selector so just blatantly I tried:

```
jest.spyOn($.fn as any,'init')
expect(($.fn as any).init).toBeCalledWith('video');
```

But my test fails. Can you guide me on how I can test for the selector in jest?

Comment: Why spy on the function? Why not test if the property has been set or not?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thank you, Don't know why it didn't occur to me, maybe because I was writing previous tests with spying pattern.